# $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, vector-space-isomorphism

> Show that $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\Bbb{Q}$.

**My attempt:**

> Let $c=$ cardinality of $\Bbb{R}$. Then we know that $\Bbb{R}$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ has basis of cardinality $c$. And for a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\Bbb{R}^n$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, we have has $\aleph_0<|\mathcal{B}|\leq |\Bbb{R}^n|=c$. So from Cantor's  hypothesis $|\mathcal{B}|=c$. Therefore bases for $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}$ have same cardinality when it is considered as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$. Thus they are isomorphic.

Is this proof logically flawless? Please correct me if required. Thank you.

**Edit** I see use of Cantor's hypothesis is not much justified. So how can we prove that the bases of both vector space have same cardinality without using this hypothesis?

Comment: Using cardinality, particularly cardinality of bases, is an excellent way to approach this problem. But the Continuum Hypothesis is not provable, so I would try to avoid using it. There are cardinality-based ways to finish the problem that don't invoke that.

Comment: Then by other means we have to prove that the bases have same cardinality. Can you give any idea to prove it that way.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^n$ themselves have the same cardinality; and you can relate the cardinality of a vector space over a field to the cardinality of the field and the dimension of the vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct if you accept the axiom of choice which assures the existence of a basis $\mathcal B_k$ of $\mathbb R^k$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. Then $\mathcal B_n$ and $\mathcal B_1$ have the same cardinality. Now you invoke the following lemma:

Given vector spaces (over any field) $V_i$ with bases $\mathcal B_i$ having the same cardinality. Then $V_1$ and $V_2$ are isomorphic.

Now cearly each function $f : \mathcal B_1 \to V_2$ extends to a unique linear map $f' : V_1 \to V_2$. Now take a bijection $\phi : \mathcal B_1 \to \mathcal B_2$ and define $f(x) = \phi(x)$. Then it is easy to verify that $f'$ is a linear isomorphism. Its inverse is induced by $\phi^{-1}$.

**Edited:**

Let $B$ a basis for $V$. Then it is easy to show that the set of all pairs having the form $(b,0)$ and $(0,b')$ with $b,b' \in B$ form a basis for $V \times V$.

It is a well-known consequence of the axiom of choice that if $B$ is infinite, then there exists a bijection $B \to  B\times\{0\} \cup \{0\} \times B$. Note that if $B$ is countable, then induction is sufficient to show this.

This shows that if $\mathcal B$ is infinite, then $V$ and $V \times V$ are isomorphic. Hence also $V$ and $V^n = V \times \ldots \times V$ are isomorphic for any $n$.

Comment: Yes, that is understood. But the query remains how to prove that both the bases have same cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $c$ depends on the underlying field ($\mathbb{Q}$). The existence of a basis requires the axiom of choice.
I do not know if the statement is correct.
You are using the same cardinality to establish isomorphism property. This does only hold for finite-dimensional vectir spaces!

Comment: So same cardinality thing does not work fir infinite dimensional vector spaces? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @user7427029 A basis $\mathcal B$ of a $k$-vector space $V$ is a subset of $V$ such that the map $G:k^{\left(\mathcal B\right)}\to V$, $G(f)=\sum_{b\in\mathcal B} f(b)b$ is an isomorphism (recall the definition $k^{(\mathcal B)}=\{f:\mathcal B\to k\text{ such that }f(x)=0\text{ for all but finitely many }x\in\mathcal B\}$, so that the sum over $b\in\mathcal B$ is actually well-defined). Therefore, two $k$-vector spaces with basis of the same cardinality are isomorphic, because they are isomorphic to $k^{(\mathcal A)}$ and $k^{(\mathcal B)}$ with $\lvert\mathcal A\rvert=\lvert\mathcal B\rvert$.